# Python : update the values in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with 1000 records where 
Group= ["India","Germany","China",....].

I am updating two columns (around 200 records where Group == 'India'): New_Operator, Level

The First two lines of code are updating the records for "New Operator" and "Level".

The **problem** is: 
3rd and 4th line of code is replacing the previously updated code (first two line):

New Operator=> previously updated as "India" => is replaced as "Local"

Level=> previously updated as "L1" => is replaced as "Non L1"

```
df.loc[(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle == 'Andhra Pradesh') | (df.Circle == 'Chennai') | (df.Circle == 'Delhi') | (df.Circle == 'Gujrat') | (df.Circle == 'Karnataka') | (df.Circle == 'Tamil Nadu')) , 'New_Operator'] = 'India'

df.loc[(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle == 'Andhra Pradesh') | (df.Circle == 'Chennai') | (df.Circle == 'Delhi') | (df.Circle == 'Gujrat') | (df.Circle == 'Karnataka') | (df.Circle == 'Tamil Nadu')) , 'Level'] = 'L1'

print(df)

df.loc[(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle != 'Andhra Pradesh') | (df.Circle != 'Chennai') | (df.Circle != 'Delhi') | (df.Circle != 'Gujrat') | (df.Circle != 'Karnataka') | (df.Circle != 'Tamil Nadu')) , 'New_Operator'] = 'Local'

df.loc[(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle != 'Andhra Pradesh') | (df.Circle != 'Chennai') | (df.Circle != 'Delhi') | (df.Circle != 'Gujrat') | (df.Circle != 'Karnataka') | (df.Circle != 'Tamil Nadu')) , 'Level'] = 'Non L1'

print(df)
```

I expect the output to be updated where Group == 'India' & according to specific "Circle" (as mentioned in code). Is there a solution to update the values without replacing the previously updated values?

Comment: That has to do with your boolean expression. If `Circle` is for instance 'Andhra Pradesh', the expression `(df.Circle != 'Andhra Pradesh') | (df.Circle != 'Chennai') | ...` will still hold, since it is not 'Chennai'

Comment: You are having the exact same criteria in both cases, except that the assigned values are different in each case. What are you trying to do with the second set of assignments? (line 3 and 4).  Why will selection between the first set and the second set by different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean expressions are not exclusive

```
(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle == 'Andhra Pradesh') |
(df.Circle == 'Chennai') |
(df.Circle == 'Delhi') ...)
```

is true if df.Circle is equal to 'Andhra Pradesh' and also :

```
(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle != 'Andhra Pradesh') |
(df.Circle != 'Chennai') | ...)
```

evaluates to true if df.Circle is equal to 'Andhra Pradesh', because the OR conditions are true for all except df.Circle != 'Andhra Pradesh' and thus overall return True.

You need to change the second set of conditions to & as in:

```
(df.Group == 'India') & ((df.Circle != 'Andhra Pradesh') &
(df.Circle != 'Chennai') & ...)
```

I would also recommend using

```
df.Circle.isin(['Andhra Pradesh','Chennai', ... ])
```

and

```
~df.Circle.isin(['Andhra Pradesh','Chennai', ... ])
```

since those methods may be easier to get right in this case